# Django Rest Framework Related Model Permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to build a simple API. I've 3 related models, User, Device, Data. (One-to-many relation between User-Device and Device-Data)

I've a problem about permissions. Right now, for User-Device relation, authenticated users can only view or edit their own Devices. (And when they create a Device, the relation is automatically established.)

I want users to be able to view, create or edit Data only for their devices. For example, a user can't create a Data or view a Data of a device that doesn't belong to him. I couldn't figure out what is the correct way to achieve this. Can you help me with this?

Here is my **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from iot_cloud_app.serializers import *
from iot_cloud_app.permissions import IsOwner

# Create your views here.

class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows devices to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsOwner,
    )

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Filter devices of the user that made the request.
        """
        return Device.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows device data to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Filter data of devices that belongs to user who made the request.
        """
        return Data.objects.all().filter(device__user=self.request.user)
```

and **serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from iot_cloud_app.models import Device, Data
from rest_framework import serializers


class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'code')


class DataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    modified = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('id', 'device', 'payload', 'created', 'modified')
```

edit: **permissions.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to do actions.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Permissions are only allowed to the owner of the device.
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also add IsOwner permission class?

Comment: I added permissions.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you override `get_queryset` method of `DataViewSet` class, users will not have access for existing objects, they will see 404 error if object's device is not related to the user. If you need 403 error instead you can implement custom permission class same as `IsOwner`:

```
class IsDeviceOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Permissions are only allowed to the owner of the device.
        return obj.device.user == request.user
```

And use it in viewset:

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows device data to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsDeviceOwner,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Filter data of devices that belongs to user who made the request.
        """
        return Data.objects.all().filter(device__user=self.request.user)
```

To limit device choice on data creation you can implement serializer's `validate_device` method:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    modified = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('id', 'device', 'payload', 'created', 'modified')
    def validate_device(self, value):
        if value.user != self.context['request'].user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong device id')
        return value
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick! For this case, why we need both a validator and a permission class? Basically, they're checking the same thing, and if I comment out permission part, it still works as I wished. (only allows creating data for owned devices)

Comment: @MertAkozcan yep, you dont really need permission since you've implemented `get_queryset` which already limited access to objects. But if you need to return 403 error instead of 404 you can use permissions instead of queryset.

Comment: Hi, when I use permissions instead of get_queryset, GET request to data endpoint returns all data records regardless of which user is logged in. Is there a way to prevent this? Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: @MertAkozcan hm.. I thought it should work:( Try to override `get_object` instead as here: https://gist.github.com/blapid/359d120bcc73609a42cb

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I'm gonna write inside overrided get_object function. What happens in my case is that when a request comes to /data endpoint, it returns all data records unexpectedly. However when a request comes to /data/<id of data that doesn't belong to logged in user> raises permission exception as expected. Is this the same situation as in the link you provided?

Comment: @MertAkozcan do you have `get_queryset` method inside `DataViewSet`? You need to add it also.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Thank you so much for the validate! This is actually the only way I found to restrict a (malicious?) user to create objects related to a parent objet they do not own. This is rather crucial detail. "has_object_permission" is called but not enforced (just returning False is not enforced) when creating a new object. And "has_permission" does not work because the object is not created yet. Without you "validate_device" function, a user could end up with a bunch of objects he never created. I also use uuid as pk. Incremental integer make it too easy to guess pk.

Comment: What would happen if you don't want to reveal if the Device exists or not. So if you want to return the same message "The Device does not exist or you don't have access to it", instead of returning two different messages: "Wrong Device ID" (in this case) and "Invalid pk - object does not exist."